# Petty Sessions Court Registers, Dublin, Ireland, 21/02/1873

Tags: ireland, court-records

Ireland, Dublin, Drumcondra:

Petty Sessions Court Registers Image 21/02/1873.

Interested in understanding script on top under particulars of order or dismissal column as indicated/marked up for Thomas Heeney as defense. in Petty Court Session. [image]

Also view of overall...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted text reads:

> compensation 1/- [1 shilling and 0 pence]; costs 1/- or
>
> [?] weeks imprisonment

The number of weeks is unclear (it looks to be smudged. a better image might be readable).

---

This type of sentence meant that the defendant had been judged to be guilty of the offence, and was required to pay the specified compensation and costs.  If s/he couldn't or wouldn't pay then s/he was to be imprisoned for the specified number of weeks.

There were 12 old pence to a shilling, and 20 shillings to the pound.

Comment: A great response to a query. Petty court as far as I see is for hedge cutting? Will advise further re post and history in Dublin lore and more. Thank you.